# Load current class into JarOutputStream

Tags: java, class, jar

I am building an application that must load the current class at runtime, and add it to a different .jar that I am creating. I have a method that adds files to a jar.

```
private static void add(File source, JarOutputStream target,
        Manifest manifest) throws IOException {
    BufferedInputStream in = null;
    try {
        String name = source.getName();
        JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(name);
        entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
        target.putNextEntry(entry);
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(source));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (true) {
            int count = in.read(buffer);
            if (count == -1)
                break;
            target.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        target.closeEntry();
    } finally {
        if (in != null)
            in.close();
    }
}
```

My problem is this: I can't seem to find out how to add the current class into a file at runtime. I have tried this:

```
File classFile= new File(getClass().getResource("MyClass.class").getPath());
```

but I get a null pointer exception. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this the main class ? Was it loaded by the bootstrap class loader? What is the package hierarchy this class lies in ?

Comment: Yes, this is the main class. It is just sitting the the default package.

Comment: Did you try adding a slash before MyClass.class: getResource("/MyClass.class") ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to get the class file as a `File` - just fetch the stream directly:

```
InputStream classFile = getClass().getResourceAsStream("MyClass.class");
```

You'll need to modify your `add` method to take a target name and an input stream, of course. (Potentially overload it, so you've still got the existing method available, which would just open the file, call the other method, then close the stream.)

Comment: How would I edit the add method to take a stream? Don't I need to pass in a file?

Comment: @TBecker: Well currently you're using three things about the file: its name, its last modified time, and the data in it (in terms of an `InputStream`). So if you specify the name and the `InputStream` for the class file, and choose some arbitrary last modified time, that's all you need, right?